# Terraform Apply and Plan do not execute sub dir together

Tags: terraform

i want to run sub dir together.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eudij.png)

cand1 - main.tf 
cand2 - main.tf 
cand3 - main.tf

run in one step

```
terraform plan/apply -option
```

i don't know option 
how to run in one step??

Comment: Please make sure you add the code to the question so there is a chance of reproducing your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider the next question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform works with a root directory as a main project location. Depending on your use case, you may want to:

a) rename all main.tf files into anything with *.tf, for example cand1.tf, cand2.tf, cand3.tf; copy them all into one folder and run terraform in there

b) create main.tf in the root folder and use the cand1, cand2 and cand3 as modules (https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/syntax)

c) check out consolidating tools like [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/) that can run multiple terraform projects as one.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve it thanks to you

Comment: Superb! could you please mark the answer as completed?